# Add to cart without page refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to achieve adding to cart without page refreshing. I am new to javascript and ajax. Please guide me. Here tried using prevent default instead of location reload. but products not adding to the cart.

```
 function addToCart(id)
    {
        if(checkAddToCartValidity()) {
            $('#addToCart').modal();
            $('.c-preloader').show();

            $.ajax({
               type:"POST",
               url: '{{ route('cart.addToCart') }}',
              // data: $('#option-choice-form').serializeArray(),
              data: {
                    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                    "id": id,
                    "quantity": 1
                },
               success: function(data){
                   $('#addToCart-modal-body').html(null);
                   $('.c-preloader').hide();
                   $('#modal-size').removeClass('modal-lg');
                   updateNavCart();
                  $('#cart_items_sidenav').html(parseInt($('#cart_items_sidenav').html())+1);
                  $('.add_to_card_sidebar').addClass('open');
                   location.reload();
                   
               }
           });
        }
        else{
            AIZ.plugins.notify('warning', 'Please choose all the options');
        }
    }
```

Comment: What specifically do you mean by *"products not adding to the cart"*?  When you debug this, are there any errors at all on the browser's development console?  In the browser's debugging tools, is the AJAX request made?  Does it contain the data you expect?  What is the server's response?  Did the server-side code perform the intended operation?  Is the `success` callback function shown here invoked?  Is there a specific operation in that callback which doesn't produce the expected result?  Please clarify what specifically fails.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @David I want to achieve products adding to cart without page refresh. I dont see any errors in my console. I replaced eventt.preventDefault(); instead of location.reload();. So I said products not adding to cart

Answer (score 0):

You could assign an ID to the html that makes up the cart-content that needs to get updated when an action gets performed. When the action gets performed try using `Document.getElementById()` to edit the contents of the cart.

Here's a quick example from me:

```
<p id="par">hello</p>
document.getElementById("par").innerHTML = "bye"
```

This code will change the text from "hello" to "bye "without refreshing the page. You can apply this to your cart as well.

Here's some docs: 
[getElementById docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) 
[HTML ID docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id/) 
[Example of cart with JS](https://codepen.io/chrisachinga/pen/MWwrZLJ)